# Excel vba: check if VLookup returns empty value, given that Vlookup substitutes empty with zero

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

So I have a table for different regions and corresponding values for different years 2014-2017. Not all regions have value for the year 2017. However, if I make a `WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)` it will return 0 if the cell in question is empty.

I need to put my special value (-1) instead of 0 if the cell for a given region is empty, however, I can't differentiate between real zeroes and zeroes `Vlookup` returns instead of empty values. How would I do it?

**EDIT**: I can't use `IsEmpty` on individual cells, because I **don't know** the result's cell's address - I loop though them in a cycle without even knowing a first argument's address. All I have is the result - either a real or a fake zero.

Comment: You can use `IsEmpty` function to check if the cell is empty.

Comment: @Egan Wolf Edited the question.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` does not return 0 if the lookup cell is empty. Only if you attempt to store the result in a number variable, will it be converted to 0.

Comment: @Ans Can you show (at least) the line of your code that uses a `VLookup`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/571018/769268)

`=if(len(vlookup(a2,f$2:g$20,2))=0,"",vlookup(a2,f$2:g$20,2))`

The trick is to use any checking functions not on `result = VLookup(...)` but rather on `VLookup` itself, before it had time to change emptiness to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if VLOOKUP returns an empty cell.

As a worksheet formula you can use:  `=IF(VLOOKUP(K9,$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE)="",-1,VLOOKUP(K9,$F$2:$G$6,2,FALSE))`

As a VBA example you could use:

```
Public Function MyVlookup(lookup_value, table_array As Range, col_index_num As Long, Optional range_lookup As Boolean = False) As Variant

    Dim ReturnValue As Variant

    ReturnValue = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, range_lookup)

    If IsEmpty(ReturnValue) Then
        MyVlookup = -1
    Else
        MyVlookup = ReturnValue
    End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think using IF, ISEmpty will solve your problem.

Use WorksheetFunction.Match to get cell address

```
currentCell= the cell in which you'll be putting value
concernedCell=The cell which can be empty

If(Isempty(concernedCell)) Then
currentCell.value=-1
Else
currentCell.value=concernedCell.value
```

Comment: Don't know the `currentCell`'s address, so it's useless. I can only play around with Vlookup result.

Comment: Could you please share your code, the point being , you are putting the result of vlookup somewhere, that must give address. Or, it may be the case that I'm missing something. Sharing code will be of great help.